# adbからアプリを無効化したい

Tags: android, adb

設定アプリのアプリケーションの一覧画面からアプリを無効化できますが、これをadbコマンドで行うことはできますか？
手元にある20台くらいの端末（機種は同じ）の中の決められたパッケージのアプリを無効化するスクリプトを書きたいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`adb`から`pm`コマンドでパッケージマネージャを起動して、類似のことはできます。

Android 4.4以降であれば、`block/unblock`コマンドが使えます。

```
// アプリを無効化
adb shell pm block　<PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
// アプリ無効化を解除
adb shell pm unblock <PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
```

Android5.0からはコマンドが変わり、`hide/unhide`になりました。

```
// アプリを無効化
adb shell pm hide　<PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
// アプリ無効化を解除
adb shell pm unhide <PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
```

類似のコマンドに`disable/enable`があり、こちらはAndroid4.0から使えますがroot権限が必要のようです？

```
// アプリを無効化（アプリ一覧からも抹消）
adb shell pm disable <PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
// アプリを無効化（アプリ一覧には残す）
adb shell pm disable-user <PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
// アプリ無効化を解除
adb shell pm enable <PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT>
```

これらのコマンドは、設定から無効化を行えないアプリも対象にできるほか、コンポーネント単位で指定できるので特定の`Activity`だけ無効化するといったことも可能です。